# Laravel 5.1 Register events at runtime

Tags: events, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel 5.1 Events registration procedure and facing a problem when trying to register custom events at runtime which are not defined in the `EventServiceProvider` class.

I have the following slightly modified Laravel 5.1 folder structure which includes a root `client` folder where I store all the client specific classes, events and view files. Folder structure is as following:

```
--app
   -- Events
     -- RecordUpdatedEvent.php
     -- more core events here...
   -- Listeners
     -- RecordUpdatedHandler.php
     -- more core listeners here...
--bootstrap
--client
  --Events
      --RecordUpdatedEvent.php
      --more client specific events...
  --Listeners
      --RecordUpdatedHandler.php
      --more client specific listeners...
  --resources
--config
--database
--resources
...etc
```

I have the following composer psr-4 setup for namespacing and autoloading:

```
"psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Client\\": "client/"
    },
```

And of course performed `composer dump-autoload -o`. So far so good and it all works.

I am trying to find a way to register client specific event handlers without manually changing the `EventServiceProvider` class every time I want to add a new client specific event (since `EventServiceProvider` is a core class that is shared between all clients).

So for example, when an `App\Events\RecordUpdatedEvent` occur I will want to also fire a `Client\Events\RecordUpdatedEvent` (or more events) by dynamically resolving the events to be fired from the database.

The problem is that when I programmatically fire a client specific event (i.e `Event::fire(Client\Events\RecordUpdatedEvent)`) it gets fired correctly but never dispatches the `Client\Listeners\RecordUpdatedHandler` class since it is never registered anywhere.

My question will be how to register new event handlers during runtime or whether there is a way to specify within the event class itself (i.e `RecordUpdatedEvent`) which Handler class to dispatch. Ideally I would be able to set a class property such as `$this->handler = "Client\Listeners\RecordUpdatedHandler"`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I get the question. One alternative is to create a Service Provider, then, in the `boot()` method you register a subscriber class:

```
 \Event::subscribe(new CustomSubscriber());
```

Ok, lets say that you want to fire a custom event in a controller class. Just put it an name:

```
public function myControllerMethod(){
    \Event::fire('test.event');
}
```

Finally, just join `test.event` with the subscriber's specific function. For example, `onTestEvent()` method will listen for `test.event` event:

```
class CustomSubscriber {

    public function onTestEvent(){
        Log::info('hello, this is a test event without editing kernel file');
    }

    // this is the trick
    public function subscribe($events){
        $events->listen('test.event', 'CustomSubscriber@onTestEvent');
    }
}
```

This technique is cool if you work with custom package development.

Comment: Thank you! this was the missing link I was looking for. Had to do some changes but it pointed me to the right direction. Do you know of any reason not to simply put the `\Event::subscribe(new CustomEventsSubscriber)` in `EventServiceProvider@boot`?

Comment: There is not difference. You can subscribe events individually at `boot()`. For my preference I like centralize the events in a unique-purpose class. But repeat, there is not difference :)

Comment: A more complete example would be to show that variables can be passed in by the ```fire``` method, ```$response = Event::fire('test.event', array($variables));```

Comment: And how do you unsubscribe from the subscribed event?

Comment: @Tofandel `app('events')->forget('event.name')` should do that.

Comment: Not really, it removes all callbacks of that event, there is no built in way to only unsubscribe from one (eg: `app('events')->forget('event.name', 'CustomSubscriber@onTestEvent')`)